# std::unique_ptr is NOT zero cost

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have setup, similar to this:

There is class similar to vector (it is implemented using std::vector).

It contains pointers to int's.

I am using my own custom allocator.

The vector does not create elements, but it can destroy elements.

In order to destroy it needs to call non static method `Allocator::deallocate(int *p)`.

If I do it with manual livetime management, I can call `Allocator::deallocate(int *p)` manually. This works, but is not RAII.

Alternatively, I can use `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter. However if I do so, the size of array became double, because each `std::unique_ptr` must contain pointer to the allocator.

Is there any way I can do it without doubling the size of the vector?

Note i do not want to templatize the class.

Here is best RAII code I come up.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>



struct MallocAllocator{
    template<class T>
    static T *allocate(size_t size = sizeof(T) ) noexcept{
        return reinterpret_cast<T *>( malloc(size) );
    }

    // this is deliberately not static method
    void deallocate(void *p) noexcept{
        return ::free(p);
    }

    // this is deliberately not static method
    auto getDeallocate() noexcept{
        return [this](void *p){
            deallocate(p);
        };
    }
};



struct S{
    std::function<void(void *)> fn;

    S(std::function<void(void *)> fn) : fn(fn){}

    auto operator()() const{
        auto f = [this](void *p){
            fn(p);
        };

        return std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(f)>{ (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)), f };
    }
};



int main(){
    MallocAllocator m;

    S s{ m.getDeallocate() };

    auto x = s();

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x));
}
```

Comment: You should add some details about the original problem you're trying... You've cornered the issues so much that to stay within the bounds you set, it is impossible to solve the "size" issue.

Comment: It is zero cost in a sense that if you tried to mimic the resulting behavior by yourself, you would have to do the same.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov That's not really true, because if the deleter is the same for each element you can wrap the container instead and only store the necessary machinery once.

Comment: Which makes me wonder whether passing a custom allocator to the _vector_ is a worthwhile goal to pursue. But allocators are not my forté. I'm also not sure where the vector fits into the given example.

Comment: You can write an allocator for `int *` that has your `MallocAllocator` instance, with `void destroy(int** ptr) { inner.deallocate(*ptr); }`

Comment: Similarly with `std::unique_ptr<int, noopDeleter>`: `void OuterAlloc::destroy(std::unique_ptr<int, noopDeleter>* ptr) { inner.deallocate(ptr->release()); }`

Comment: "*If I do it with manual livetime management, I can call Allocator::deallocate(int *p) manually. This works, but is not RAII.*" Sure it is. RAII is about your class's *interface* to the outside world. What happens *within* your class doesn't specifically need to be RAII. What matters is that users of your class can expect the lifetimes of internal resources to be scoped to the lifetime of the external one.

Comment: Try a high performance heap allocator like jemalloc, it might just outperform your custom allocators.

Comment: @rustyx nothing can perform arena allocator with no op deallocate.

Comment: Jemalloc can. It has support to deallocate an entire arena.

Comment: but in order to do so, I am sure, you need to wrap it as custom allocator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. If you want your `unique_ptr` to store a reference to non-static deleter, there is nothing you can do about that, it will have to store it somewhere.

Some ways to work around this:

1. If you are using allocator-aware data structure, pass you allocator to it and don't use `unique_ptr`'s, use the actual data type as a stored type.
2. Wrap you allocated objects around some sort of manager that would deallocate those objects when needed. You lose RAII inside it, but to outside code it will still be RAII. You can even transfer the ownership of some objects from this manager to the outside code and you'll only have to use custom deleter there.
3. (not recommended) Use some global state that you can access from deleter to make it size 0.